# install a phonegap plugin in a cordova project

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have seen many posts with instructions on how to install a cordova plugin in a phonegap project, but what about installing a phonegap plugin in a cordova project?

is it basically the same or there are some differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the difference is your project. If your project create using cordova, you need to use cordova command to install cordova plugin. If phonegap, using phonegap command to install phonegap plugin. But the reality is both plugins are same and came from same resource.

Comment: So, just to clear it out, if I have a cordova project started from 
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
and I type 
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/rossmartin/phonegap-dropbox-sync (just one phonegap for instance)
this will install everything like for any other cordova plugin such 
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer ?

Comment: same. as long it related to phonegap and cordova.